# How to paste from the clipboard to Google Colab when in Vim mode

Tags: vim, google-colaboratory

How does one paste the contents of the clipboard into Google Colab when in Vim mode?

Answer (score 1):

To paste from the clipboard into Colab when in Vim mode:

1. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter `NORMAL` mode.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste clipboard contents.